# Regex to match all words that startswith and endswith specific characters in string

Tags: python, regex, list, word-boundary

How can I fix my regex pattern to match every word that startswith "X" and endswith "Z"?

Code:

```
import re

#input
s = "xaz xazx xaxsza zsxdaszdx zasxz xaaz xaaaz"

pattern1 = "x.*z"
pattern2 = "\bx.*z\b"
pattern3 = "x.*?z"
pattern4 = "\b^x.*z$\b"
pattern5 = "\Bx.*z\B"
#also tried using \s, \S, ^ and $... 

re.findall(pattern, s)
```

Desired Output:

```
out = ["xaz", "xaaz", "xaaaz"]
```

How can I achieve this?

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aGXyQP/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of notes on your patterns:

- `"x.*z"` - matches `x`, then *any chars other than line break as many as possible up to the last occurrence of `z`
- `"\bx.*z\b"` - a backspace symbol, then the same as above, and again a backspace symbol
- `"x.*?z"` - an `x`, then *any chars other than line break as *few* as possible up to the *first* occurrence of `z`
- `"\b^x.*z$\b"` - a backspace symbol followed with the start of the string, which is already signalling a failure, any 0+ chars up to the `z` followed with the end of string, and then a backspace symbol
- `"\Bx.*z\B"` - a non-word boundary, `x`, any 0+ chars up to the last `z` that is not followed with a word boundary.

You need to use a raw string literal so that `\b` could denote a word boundary.

So, you may use

```
s = "xaz xazx xaxsza zsxdaszdx zasxz xaaz xaaaz"
pattern = r"\bx\w*z\b"
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
# => ['xaz', 'xaaz', 'xaaaz']
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/H5VARF)

If you want to match words with letters only, use `r"\bx[^\W\d_]*z\b"`.

**Pattern demo**:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `x` - an `x`
- `\w*` - 0+ word chars (letters/digits/`_`) (the `[^\W\d_]` construct will match any letter, digits and `_` are substracted in the "double negative" construction)
- `z` a `z`
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary.

Note that in case you only have "words" separated with spaces, you may get the results with

```
[x for x in s.split() if x.startswith('x') and x.endswith('z')]
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/PP9r8g)

Comment: Perfect, very helpful! Thanks for the code and the explanation! I'm learning regex and this helped me a lot!

Comment: Note that `"\b"` is not the same as `r"\b"` and `"\B"` is equal to `r"\B"`. Use raw string literals in most cases when defining regex patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Regex: \bx\S+z\b

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/XuJybA/2

1. Search for words using the word boundary: **\b**
2. See that the string begins with **x**
3. Then match anything except spaces **\S**
4. And make sure the word ends with **z**

Comment: Very interesting! I was trying to achieve something like this in my head.. Thanks for your help! Btw, it seems that `\bx\S+z\b` works too!

Comment: Yes. I started with something else in mind like words that start and end with the same letter, corrected it :)